# How to get Exponent/Modulus from KeyPair generated in Xamarin for Android key store

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, rsa, x509certificate

I have Xamarin (android) application.
I need to generate public/private key pair and then get Exponent and Modulus for other app logic.
In my other native Android application I have this implemented - code is in production and works fine - here is shortened **JAVA** version:

```
// Android key store
KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
store.load(null);

// Key generation params
KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder keySpecBuilder =
            new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder("my-cert", KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_VERIFY)
                .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_NONE, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256)
                .setSignaturePaddings(KeyProperties.SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
                .setKeySize(2048);

// Generate key pair
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, store.getProvider());              
kpg.initialize(keySpecBuilder.build());
KeyPair keyPair = kpg.generateKeyPair();

// Get public key
RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey)keyPair.getPublic();

// Get exponent and modulus
BigInteger exp = publicKey.getPublicExponent();
BigInteger mod = publicKey.getModulus();
```

When I tried to write exactly same code to C#/Xamarin, I was stopped with problem of getting Exponent/Modulus from generated keys. Nor public key neither private key has these properties.

Question: **how to get Exponent and Modulus in Xamarin-C#, if I have Java.Security.KeyPair object generated** (see **C#** example below):

```
// Android key store
var store = KeyStore.GetInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
store.Load(null);
// Key generation params
var keyGenParameterSpecBuilder =
                new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder("my-cert", KeyStorePurpose.Sign | KeyStorePurpose.Verify)
                .SetDigests(KeyProperties.DigestNone, KeyProperties.DigestSha256)
                .SetSignaturePaddings(KeyProperties.SignaturePaddingRsaPkcs1)
                .SetKeySize(2048);
// Generate key pair                
var kpg = KeyPairGenerator.GetInstance(KeyProperties.KeyAlgorithmRsa, _keyStore.Provider); 
kpg.Initialize(keyGenParameterSpecBuilder.Build());
var keyPair = kpg.GenKeyPair();

var publicKey = keyPair.Public; // has type of IPublicKey
// How to get PublicExponent and Modulus?
// IPublicKey has no needed properties

// Not possible to cast to IRSAPublicKey, which has needed properties
var rsaPublicKey = publicKey as IRSAPublicKey; // = null
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaCast method must be used to cast IPublicKey to IRSAPublicKey type. 
Then Exponent and Modulus are accessible via properties.

```
var rsaPublicKey = publicKey.JavaCast<IRSAPublicKey>();
var e = rsaPublicKey.PublicExponent;
var m = rsaPublicKey.Modulus;
```